# Get only selected custom taxonomy

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields, terms

I have this code:

```
        $post_types = get_post_types();


    if($post_types)
    {
        foreach($post_types as $post_type)
        {
            $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post_type);
            $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);
            if($taxonomies)
            {
                foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy)
                {
                    if(!is_taxonomy_hierarchical($taxonomy)) continue;
                    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => false));
                    if($terms)
                    {
                        foreach($terms as $term)
                        {
                            $value = $taxonomy . ':' . $term->term_id;

                            if( $simple_value )
                            {
                                $value = $term->term_id;
                            }

                            $choices[$post_type_object->label . ': ' . $taxonomy][$value] = $term->name; 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This will list all of the Taxonomy I have. But I only need thoose taxonomies which has product_cat category. Any suggestion how could I change this?

Answer (score 0):

Before your first `foreach` loop, at the top of the script, define an empty array to house what you're after:

```
$taxWith_product_cat = array();
```

Now since you're looping through all taxonomies and all terms therein, in the terms loop `foreach($terms as $term)`, check if the current term is `product_cat`. If it is, add the terms taxonomy to the new array:

```
if ($term->slug == 'product_cat ')
    $taxWith_product_cat[] = $taxonomy;
```

There you have it. Now at the end of the script, you have an array of taxonomies that contain a term of `product_cat`:

```
echo "<pre>".print_r(￼$taxWith_product_cat,true)."</pre>";
```